# Can $\mathfrak{so}(3,1) \sim \mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$ be supersymmetrized?

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, superalgebra

My question is of course linked to physics, since I'm a student of physics.

The symmetry algebra of 3d de-sitter spacetimes is $\mathfrak{so}(3,1) \sim \mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$ which is also the Lorentz algebra in 4D. But Lorentz algebra can be supersymmetrized in 4D with only one grassmanian generator. What I mean by that mathematically is "the algebra can be embedded in a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ graded Lie algebra which satisfies certain axioms ([see here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.cmp/1103900590))".

whereas literature is filled with statements (such as section II of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.01678.pdf)) "de Sitter algebra cannot be supersymmetrized unless we have even $\mathcal{N}$(= no. of grassmanian generators)" Why so? How does the dimension play a role in saying whether I can write a superalgebra from a lie algebra?

Comment: Your notation suggests groups, but you seem to be talking about Lie algebras which are often denoted in lower case and/or Fraktur type, i.e. $\mathfrak{so}(3,1)$ and $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C)$. For clarity I also point out (because there has been confusion about this in many questions here) that the isomorphism of these two is an isomorphism of *real* Lie algebras, i.e. we view $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C)$ as a four-dimensional Lie algebra over $\mathbb R$ here.

Comment: That being said, can you remind us what a de Sitter algebra and a (non)-compact R charge is, and give a more precise source for what "one often hears"? If the notion of compactness there is related to the one I know, there is no contradiction here because these Lie algebras are very non-compact.

Comment: Argh, in my first comment please read "we view $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C)$ as a **six**-dimensional Lie algebra over $\mathbb R$ here" at the end.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Thanks for the suggestions. I've edited the question to the best of my abilities. Let me know your thoughts.